# Why totalDocsExamined is non zero even when query uses index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

From the official MongoDB docs its written, that a query is covered if it uses an index:

> When an index covers a query, the explain result has an IXSCAN stage
> that is not a descendant of a FETCH stage, and in the executionStats,
> the totalDocsExamined is 0.

Then why when I find by _id, which is an index, and I configure the `.explain()` method, I get this result: `totalDocsExamined = 1`?

This is the query:

```
db.getCollection('orders').find({_id: ObjectId("70c457ef3f969259164df3e1")}).explain("executionStats")
```

Answer (score 1):

That query isn't covered.

From the doc:

> A covered query is a query that can be satisfied entirely using an index.

"satisfied entirely" means that all fields that are either queried or might be returned are contained in the index.

In order for that query to be covered by the default index on the _id field, it would need to have a projection that excluded all other fields, such as:

```
db.getCollection('orders').find({_id: ObjectId("70c457ef3f969259164df3e1")}, {_id:1})
```

Comment: Still got `totalDocsExamined = 1`, also, if I have the _id in my hand, and I filter for this _id field only, then why should I query from first of all?

Comment: The covered query is a special use case.  For most queries you will want data returned that is not in the index, so it will need to examine at least the number of documents returned to retrieve that data.